# Align text by numbers in table columns

Tags: tables, math-mode, horizontal-alignment, dcolumn

I need to align the text in columns by decimals in the numbers. However the numbers go together with text so I can not simple use dcolumn package in 5th column as in the 1st one. If I split to more columns - the spaces are too big.

And I can not use siunitx since I have to use Slunits and they just don't work together.

The code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{array}
\newcommand{\sta}{\mathrm{(stat.)}}
\newcommand{\sys}{\mathrm{(sys.)}}

\usepackage{dcolumn}
\newcolumntype{d}[1]{D{.}{.}{#1} }

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}
        \begin{center}
            \begin{tabular}{|d{1.3}cd{1.3}| d{3.4} l | l l |}%{|lcl|ll|ll|}
                \hline
                \multicolumn{3}{|c|}{\strut$x$ range}    
                & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{  measurement 1 (units)} 
                & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{  measurement 2 (units)} \\
                \hline
                0.000 &--& 0.005   &   452.4444 & $  \pm$   43.4444$\sta\,\pm$  23.4444$\,\sys$ &     87.4444     & $  \pm$    7.4444$\,\sta$ \\
                0.025 &--& 0.010   &   645.4444 & $  \pm$   45.4444$\sta\,\pm$  42.4444$\,\sys$ &    410.4444     & $  \pm$   40.4444$\,\sta$ \\
                0.010 &--& 0.015   &   458.4444 & $  \pm$   45.4444$\sta\,\pm$  36.4444$\,\sys$ &     79.4444     & $  \pm$    4.4444$\,\sta$ \\
                0.025 &--& 0.025   &   167.4444 & $  \pm$   18.4444$\sta\,\pm$  14.1747$\,\sys$ &     46.4444     & $  \pm$    4.4444$\,\sta$ \\
                0.045 &--& 0.030   &    52.4444 & $  \pm$    4.4444$\sta\,\pm$   4.4444$\,\sys$ &     18.7175     & $  \pm$    4.4444$\,\sta$ \\
                0.040 &--& 0.090   &     4.4444 & $  \pm$    4.4444$\sta\,\pm$   4.4444$\,\sys$ &      4.4444     & $  \pm$    4.4444$\,\sta$ \\
                \hline
            \end{tabular}
        \end{center}
        \caption{text.}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: if i were doing this, i'd take a "lazy" approach -- insert spaces the width of a digit in appropriate places to align the digits.  `\newcommand{\0}(\phantom{0}}` gives a command that is easy to remember.

Comment: @barbara-beeton thank you! it actually solved my problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would recommend that you provide more information in the argument of `tabular` about the structure of the table. That way, the body of the tabular environment need contain only numbers.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{dcolumn}
\newcolumntype{d}[1]{D{.}{.}{#1} }

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|d{1.3} @{--} d{1.3} | 
                 d{3.4} @{${}\pm{}$} 
                 d{2.4} @{(stat.)${}\pm{}$} 
                 d{2.4} @{(sys.)\hspace{\tabcolsep}} |
                 d{3.4} @{${}\pm{}$} 
                 d{2.4} @{(stat.)\hspace{\tabcolsep}} |}
\hline
  \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{\strut$x$ range}
& \multicolumn{3}{ c|}{measurement 1 (units)} 
& \multicolumn{2}{ c|}{measurement 2 (units)} \\
\hline
0.000 & 0.005 & 452.4444 & 43.4444 & 23.4444 & 87.4444 & 7.4444 \\
0.025 & 0.010 & 645.4444 & 45.4444 & 42.4444 &410.4444 & 40.4444 \\
0.010 & 0.015 & 458.4444 & 45.4444 & 36.4444 & 79.4444 & 4.4444 \\
0.025 & 0.025 & 167.4444 & 18.4444 & 14.1747 & 46.4444 &  4.4444 \\
0.045 & 0.030 &  52.4444 &  4.4444 &  4.4444 & 18.7175 & 4.4444 \\
0.040 & 0.090 &   4.4444 &  4.4444 &  4.4444 &  4.4444 & 4.4444 \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{text.}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```